# How do I see or manipulate uploaded files in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, forms, mean-stack

I'm currently working on a MEAN stack blog for my portfolio. My goal is to be able to store an HTML file or .docx file in my Mongoose database to recall later as the individual blog posts. As a first step, I created this form:

```
<form>
    File: <input type = 'file' ng-model = "new_post.file">
    <input type = 'date' ng-model = "new_post.date">
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" ng-click = "save_post(new_post)">
</form>
```

In the Angular controller, I have this code listening for that form:

```
$scope.save_post = function(new_post){
    console.log(new_post);
    if(new_post.file){
        console.log("yo");
    }
}
```

When I enter the HTML document I want to store and submit the form, the `console.log` shows the `new_post.date` information. However, `new_post.file` doesn't show up in the log and "yo" doesn't print. When I've tried to log `new_post.file`, it shows up as `undefined`. How can I store the file in a form that my controller can recognize so I can pass it through my factory and ultimately up to my database?